# Using java methods in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want to call some methods in my jsp file. I have a class file with some methods and I want to use some of the methods used in that class file. I have gone through page import in JSP, but still I didn't get any idea about how to do that. I have installed some extra libraries and which is required to run those methods. Do I need to place the libraries in the server where I am using the jsp file. Can anyone suggest me how to do that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- add the jars in `WEB-INF/lib`
- [Avoid using java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202), use EL and/or `jsp:useBean` isntead.

Comment: Where can I found the folder in windows. I have installed tomcat in "D:\tomcat".

Comment: did you read a tutorial before starting? The path is `tomcat/webapps/yourwebapp/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Can you please share some good tutorial link for using the java methods in JSP file

Comment: I gave you a link to a tutorial showing how not to use java methods in jsp. The tutorial that you should start with is perhaps the official jsp and servlet tutorial.

Comment: +1: For pointing at the only right direction, despite doing it a bit forcibly.

Answer (score 1):

Use @page Directive tag to include the java class file and create object in scriptlet(<% %>) tag and use the methods of that class as you want..